# Is the use of explicit ' == true' comparison always bad?

Tags: coding-style, conditions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a big deal out of == true?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true)

I've been looking at a lot of code samples recently, and I keep noticing the use of...

```
if( expression == true )
    // do something...
```

and...

```
x = ( expression == true ) ? x : y;
```

I've tended to always use...

```
x = ( expression ) ? x : y;
```

and...

```
if( expression )
    // do something...
```

Where `== true` is implicit (and obvious?)

Is this just a habit of mine, and I'm being picky about the explicit use of `== true`, or is it simply bad practice?

Comment: For me it depends. Sometimes in Java When I'm given a possibly null Boolean (we'll call x) I'll write `if (x == null || x == true)` because I think it's easier to read than `if (x == null || x)` or `if(x != false)`. Of course depending on the specification i might have `x != null` etc.

Comment: I would argue that programming languages that insist on using `== true` are lacking in logical simplicity.

Comment: It is hardly worth thinking about. There are SO MANY MUCH WORSE things than "x == True" as far as readability is concerned. If thats the worst thing you find on any given day consider yourself lucky.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It usually depends on the language (you can find issues around implicit boolean casting of variables in some situations).

If you're using a language like Javascript, you can have unexpected behavior in some cases (watch [Douglas Crockford's Google talk](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/index.html#_js_goodparts) - it's in there somewhere, and a good talk to watch anyway).

As there are these strange cases that can be a pain in the arse to track down and fix, I've made a point to always be explicit in my own evaluations (even using `===` when using a language that supports it).

The trick is to be **consistent** throughout your code base. When you start tossing special cases in the mix (i.e. "well, if this makes sense to *me*, then I'll use implicit coercion), someone's bound to get confused somewhere and start misusing it (and/or misunderstanding it). The simplest thing to do is to just stick to one rule throughout - to me, being explicit makes sense.

Comment: +1 I personally prefer implicit (less code is normally better), however consistent code is by far the most important thing

Comment: What's icky with C and NULL? Of all the languages I've used, I like its handling of true/false the best. More weakly-type languages (PHP, JavaScript) do some unintuitive things, and strongly-typed languages are annoying.

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't matter what it points to, it's not being dereferenced. if(c) and if(*c) mean different things.

Comment: @DemianBrecht: The condition will evaluate to true, since the pointer isn't NULL. Nothing unintuitive about that.

Comment: @Austin, Hippo: Yep, I'm dumb.. Been a long day. I **do** remember running into horrendous issues before (release builds usually), but I can't remember offhand now what, exactly, they were.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes.

I'm going to go ahead and response with a big yes, since there are no other responses yet. But, always open to new data suggesting otherwise.

It's a yes because the expression already evaluates to a boolean. Your explicit testing of that boolean is adding nothing of value to the program. In fact, it increases the surface area for error (typos, future changes, etc).

> Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away. -- *Antoine de Saint-Exupery*

Comment: +1 It is especially obvious when the expression is a well named method e.g. `if (dog.isBarking()) { // tell it to shut up }` so for better readability keep [replace temp with query](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-temp-with-query) in mind.

Comment: -1. It does generally evaluate to a Boolean, but usually through implicit casting that uses rules that are often much less strict than the rest of the language. One can enforce that the argument is actually a Boolean using the `== TRUE` form, avoiding these loose implicit casting rules. In a type-safer language (like Haskell), I wouldn't bother with the `== TRUE`, but in most mainstream languages, I think it works around language shortcomings.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

First off, to those who say no to the situation with no exceptions, I challenge you to find a situation where a coding convention fits all use cases. This is no different.

Now in a situation where you have a simple expression being evaluated I would not add `== true` to the code. It is largely self explanatory and I know my coworkers would understand what is happening without much though. In addition you may fall into the debugging joy that is writing `var = true` rather than `var == true`.

```
while (flag) {
  // iterate
}
```

In a situation where you have a function inside of the comparison, unless the method is of the `isSomeCondition()` variety, I would add the `== true`. In my opinion doing so with an ambiguous method makes it more clear what you expect the code to be. After all, it is easy to miss a `!`.

```
while (largeAmbiguousCheckingMethod(input) == true) {

}
```

In this situation you should immediately know what the intent is, assuming a well name method, and you do not run into the problem of accidental assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean types should not require explicit testing, whereas non-boolean variables should require explicit testing.

The test condition should be thought of as a boolean itself--the result of which is either true or false.  With this premise, explicit testing of a boolean is redundant and implicit testing of non-booleans is a type mis-match.  Furthermore, if the coding style is consistent, an implicit test serves as a good reminder to the reader that the variable is a boolean type.

Code is read far more often than it is written so please be as kind as practical to the next person reading your code.